# add a specific file without typing the entire path out?

Tags: git

`git status`

```
modified:   src/main/java/common/fileOption/FileOption.java
modified:   src/main/java/framework/Main.java
modified:   src/main/java/framework/utils/FileUtils.java
```

I would like to `git add` one of the above files, is there a quick way to do so without having to type out the entire path?

I am hoping for a mechanism to reference one of them perhaps by number. Say I want to add the last file only, then maybe something like `git add --something 3`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [**Interactive Staging**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) Git Tool.

If you run `git add` with the `-i` or `--interactive` option, it opens an interactive shell mode, displaying something like this:

```
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-3 src/main/java/common/fileOption/FileOption.java
  2:    unchanged        +0/-3 src/main/java/framework/Main.java
  3:    unchanged        +0/-3 src/main/java/framework/utils/FileUtils.java

*** Commands ***
  1: [s]tatus     2: [u]pdate     3: [r]evert     4: [a]dd untracked
  5: [p]atch      6: [d]iff       7: [q]uit       8: [h]elp
What now> a
  1: src/main/java/common/fileOption/FileOption.java
  2: src/main/java/framework/Main.java
  3: src/main/java/framework/utils/FileUtils.java
Add untracked>> 3
  1: src/main/java/common/fileOption/FileOption.java
  2: src/main/java/framework/Main.java
* 3: src/main/java/framework/utils/FileUtils.java
Add untracked>> <press enter>
added 1 path

*** Commands ***
  1: [s]tatus     2: [u]pdate     3: [r]evert     4: [a]dd untracked
  5: [p]atch      6: [d]iff       7: [q]uit       8: [h]elp
What now> q
```

If you now write `git status`, you can see, that your chosen file (FileUtils.java) is added.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to git add one of the above files, is there a quick way to do so without having to type out the entire path?

You can use a pattern to add the specific file you want. To add the last file in your example, you can do:

```sh
$ git add *FileUtils*
```

Comment: My advice is to add quotes: `git add "*FileUtils*"` — just for the case there're unwanted files in the current directory that match the wildcards. Git interprets the wildcards itself.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is what the X terminal select/paste conventions are for: drag-select the name, middle-click paste behaves as if you'd typed the name without even touching the mouse, and it uses the "selection" buffer directly without going through the clipboard.